# Как ипользовать функции WinAPI в Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, winapi

Задача:
Хочю написать на Node.js програмку аналогичную Clickermann. Не настолько сложную, и попроще.

Что хочю реализовать:
Из Clickermann интересует реализация кликов мышкой в Windows по заранее заданным координатам, выделение текста и ввод через нажатие на клавишу.

Вопрос:
Как вызвать с Node.js функцию WinAPI Например для клика по координатам?

Поискал, но интернете не нашел ответа. Буду благодарен за подсказку!

Comment: например: [win32-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/win32-api), [winapi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winapi)

Answer (score 2):

Я думаю, [node-ffi](https://github.com/rbranson/node-ffi) может помочь с этим. `node-ffi` 
предоставляет функциональность для загрузки и вызова динамических библиотек. 
С `node-ffi` вы можете получить доступ, например, к библиотеке `user32` и вызывать функционал из `node.js`

```
var FFI = require('node-ffi');

function TEXT(text){
   return new Buffer(text, 'ucs2').toString('binary');
}

var user32 = new FFI.Library('user32', {
   'MessageBoxW': [
      'int32', [ 'int32', 'string', 'string', 'int32' ]
   ]
});

var OK_or_Cancel = user32.MessageBoxW(
   0, TEXT('I am Node.JS!'), TEXT('Hello, World!'), 1
);
```

Перевод c [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775201/call-windows-api-from-node-js-msg/15775312):